# What http request should I use if I am using the findAndUpdate command in ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, httprequest, reactivemongo, findandmodify

What **http request** should I use if I am using the [findAndUpdate](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericCollection@findAndUpdate%5BQ,U%5D%28selector:Q,update:U,fetchNewObject:Boolean,upsert:Boolean,sort:Option%5BGenericCollection.this.pack.Document%5D,fields:Option%5BGenericCollection.this.pack.Document%5D%29%28implicitselectorWriter:GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer%5BQ%5D,implicitupdateWriter:GenericCollection.this.pack.Writer%5BU%5D,implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future%5BGenericCollection.this.BatchCommands.FindAndModifyCommand.FindAndModifyResult%5D) command in ReactiveMongo. My CRUD requests are routed like this:

```
GET       /api/1.1/r/:collName                  controllers.admin.MongoC.index(collName: String)
GET       /api/1.1/r/:collName/:id              controllers.admin.MongoC.read(collName: String, id: BSONObjectID)
POST      /api/1.1/c/:collName                  controllers.admin.MongoC.create(collName: String)
PUT       /api/1.1/u/:collName/:id/:many        controllers.admin.MongoC.update(collName: String, id: BSONObjectID, many: Boolean)
DELETE    /api/1.1/d/:collName/:id              controllers.admin.MongoC.delete(collName: String, id: BSONObjectID)
```

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307215/reactivemongo-findandmodify-clarification#answer-33319275) provided by @cchantep to construct the findAndUpdate command (but in the JSON collection format - as I am using the JSON plugin in the Play framework) like so:

**MongoRepo.scala**

```
  protected def getCollection(collName: String): Future[JSONCollection] = database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection](collName))

  def findAndUpdate(collName: String)(selector: JsObject, update: JsObject, oProjection: Option[JsObject]): Future[Option[JsObject]] = {

    getCollection(collName).flatMap(
      _.findAndUpdate(selector, Json.obj("$set" -> update), fetchNewObject = true, upsert = true, fields = oProjection)
        .map(_.result[JsObject])
    )

  }
```

With the controller looking like this:

**MongoC.scala**

```
   def getQueryParameterJSV(param: String) = { implicit request: Request[JsValue] =>

       val oQueryStr = request.getQueryString(param)

       oQueryStr match {
           case Some(_) => Json.parse(oQueryStr.get).asInstanceOf[JsObject]
           case None => Json.obj()
       }

   }

   def findAndUpdate(collName: String, id: BSONObjectID) = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request: Request[JsValue] =>

       val q = getQueryParameterJSV("q")(request)
       val p = getQueryParameterJSV("p")(request)
       val doc = request.body.as[JsObject]

       mongoRepo.findAndUpdate(collName)(q, doc, Some(p)).map(widget => Ok(Json.toJson(widget)))

   }
```

And the route:

**admin.routes**

```
PUT      /api/1.1/ur/:collName/:id        controllers.admin.MongoC.findAndUpdate(collName: String, id: BSONObjectID)
```

I am using **Postman** to test and when I query this URL I get the updated document as it should look but querying the collection I can see that it still contains the old values. My other CRUD commands are working correctly Any help/knowledge would be very useful. Thanks

Comment: Post your code, and what the error is.

Comment: "but this did not work" is quite un-specific

Comment: @cchantep I've edited the question for better insight. Let me know if you can spot anything or think of anything. Many thanks

Comment: @Callum - the question has been edited/updated. Many thanks

Comment: @cchantep - any thoughts on this with the above posted code?

Comment: OK. It seems that ReactiveMongo is not well documented enough currently to answer this and no one knows